# Installing nagios 3.5.1 with epel repo

Tags: centos, yum, ansible, nagios

I am trying to install nagios-core 3.5.1 with yum using epel repo. I am facing problems since the old versions of nagios has been removed from epel-repo. The latest epel-repo is coming with nagios 4.3.2.
I am using ansible to provision the nagios.

This is what I see the output of `yum info nagios` after adding the epel-repo.

```
Available Packages
Name        : nagios
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 4.3.2
Release     : 5.el6
Size        : 1.7 M
Repo        : epel
Summary     : Host/service/network monitoring program
URL         : https://www.nagios.org/projects/nagios-core/
License     : GPLv2
Description : Nagios is a program that will monitor hosts and services on your
            : network.  It has the ability to send email or page alerts when a
            : problem arises and when a problem is resolved.  Nagios is written
            : in C and is designed to run under Linux (and some other *NIX
            : variants) as a background process, intermittently running checks
            : on various services that you specify.
            :
            : The actual service checks are performed by separate "plugin" programs
            : which return the status of the checks to Nagios. The plugins are
            : available at https://github.com/nagios-plugins/nagios-plugins
            :
            : This package provides the core program, web interface, and documentation
            : files for Nagios. Development files are built as a separate package.
```

Comment: Do you want to specifically install it using `yum` or using `rpm` is OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to install it using `rpm`, download the package [here](https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/nagios/3.5.1/1.el6/x86_64/nagios-3.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm) and install it :

```
rpm -Uvh nagios-3.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

---

Try and see if the older version of nagios is still available (Double check just to be sure. You don't wanna jump through hoops for no reason)

```
yum --showduplicates list nagios | expand
```

If the older version does not exist :

Disable the new EPEL repo in `/etc/yum/yum.repos.d/`

Add the old EPEL repo :

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

Make sure to enable the old repo in `/etc/yum/yum.repos.d/` and then install `nagios`

```
yum install nagios -y
```

Comment: Thanks,
Yeah, I got that as a workaround. I am facing a different issue. Our application is provisioned using Ansible(https://www.ansible.com/). For now, we are saying install nagios by giving the remote RPM link in ansible tasks, but I am not sure how long these remote URLs for RPMs will be valid. Is it possible/legal create a local cache for these RPMs.

Comment: I don't know about legality(I don't see a reason why it would be illegal), but yes, creating a local cache would be the best way to go for Ansible.

Comment: Is there a place where I can check about this, because few people have suggested me for this.

Comment: @Mritunjay, try https://law.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Conveniently you decided not to bother supplying your distro version, however through powers of deduction I provide a link to the EL6 packages, courtesy of fedora koji (which happens to be the source of epel):

https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=460533

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, Let me know what else you want to know I will update my question.
However, if this happens to be the EPEL repo, how can I install it and use along with EPEL-release-6.8.

Comment: Thanks,
Yeah, I got that as a workaround. I am facing a different issue. Our application is provisioned using Ansible(https://www.ansible.com/). For now, we are saying install nagios by giving the remote RPM link in ansible tasks, but I am not sure how long these remote URLs for RPMs will be valid. Is it possible/legal create a local cache for these RPMs.